# Pass variables to javascript when RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add method is used

Tags: telerik

I am using RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add method to call javascript.
when I usecode like this

```
RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(@"deletecatandforms('success');"
```

the script will execute successfully.

but

```
string countAll = DeleteAll_CatryAnd_Form("count");
RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(@"deletecatandforms('"+countAll+"');");
```

is not working.
So how to pass this?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-execute-custom-javascript.html

Comment: its because there is an escape sequence in my string. thats why its not working. i cleared it. thanks for the replay...